# Maven cargo uberwar : how to exclude a dependancy

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, merge, cargo

I'm trying to use the Maven cargo uberwar plugin.
I would like to do that :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>src/assemble/merge.xml</descriptor>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.first.war</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyFirstWar</artifactId>
        <type>war</type>
        <exclusions> 
            <exclusion> 
                <groupId>javassist</groupId> 
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId> 
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.second.war</groupId>
        <artifactId>MySecondWar</artifactId>
        <type>war</type>
            <exclusions> 
        <exclusions> 
            <exclusion> 
                <groupId>javassist</groupId> 
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId> 
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But it doesn't work, javassist is still in my libs after install my uberwar.

I don't want to make the exclusions in my two wars, I want to do the exclusion in my uberwar.
This solution doesn't work, is there any other one ?

Thanks for help

Comment: The `cargo-maven2-plugin` is intended for functional testing but not for repackaging. Based on the [docs|(http://cargo.codehaus.org/Merging+WAR+files) i assume you missed to changed the packaging type `<packaging>uberwar</packaging>`. In that case you can't exclude deps from the deps, cause the deps are `wars` and not only dependencies for a project.

Comment: The packaging type of my Pom.xml il already uberwar.
I solve my problem by adding a antrun plugin on my pom who delete the jar after I execute the maven install.
But maybe there is a better way to do that...

Answer (score 0):

For each war you should set scope provided for javassist. Just like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId> 
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```